# make file vpath not replacement

Tags: makefile, vpath

i have little problem with making a make file, this is the code :

```
SHELL = /bin/sh

CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall
VPATH = src:obj

HEADERS := parser.h
dirs = out obj

%.o : mkdirs %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) -c $(word 2,$^) -o obj/$@ 

all : parser.o
    ar cr out/libsip.a $<  

clean : 
    rm -f -r $(dirs)

mkdirs :
    mkdir -p $(dirs)
```

when i try to execute make i get this error :

```
mkdir -p out obj
gcc -c src/parser.c -o obj/parser.o 
ar cr out/libsip.a parser.o
file parser.o not found
```

i don't understand why parser.o don't get replaced by the right path, i used automatic variable

Answer (score 1):

```
%.o : mkdirs %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) -c $(word 2,$^) -o obj/$@ 

all : parser.o
    ar cr out/libsip.a $<
```

You are telling make to create a `parser.o` file in the current directory.

Your `%.o` rule then creates the file in the `obj` directory not the current directory.

The `ar` command then can't find it.

`VPATH` is for finding prerequisites. If `obj/parser.o` already existed then make would find it for the `all` target I believe.

See [How Not to Use VPATH](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/).

Comment: the file obj/parser.o exist but parser.o don't get replaced by the real path

Comment: I meant exists when you start make. And yes, it doesn't because that's not the prerequisite make tried to build. It tried to build `parser.o` you just happened to create `obj/parser.o` but make doesn't know that.

Comment: ah ok i think i understand, but can you propose a solution to me?

Comment: @karim Yes, read the link I included. (Essentially don't use `VPATH` for this it doesn't work the way you want.)